# How can I perform a jQuery post with a string of data?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, vb.net, post

So I'm wanting to create a "POST" to another page.  I want to do it like the following...

```
$.ajax({

    type: "POST",
    url: "maintain.aspx",
    data: { key1:value1, key2:value2, key3:value3 },
    success: function(msg){
        alert("Done!");
    }

});
```

The problem is I don't have data in the form of variables.  Instead I'm supplied with the data in a string formatted like so...

```
&myvar=1&thisguy=dave&thatguy=martin
```

How can I get the key/value information from that string into the `data: {}` section of the ajax call?  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `data` property can be either an object as you have it, or a query string.  So you can simply use it as-is.  (though you may need to strip the leading `&`).

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "maintain.aspx",
    data: "myvar=1&thisguy=dave&thatguy=martin",
    success: function(msg){
        alert("Done!");
    }
});
```

Comment: This is correct - @daveomcd please check the jQuery API at: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var str = "&myvar=1&thisguy=dave&thatguy=martin";

var params = str.split('&');

var objData = {};
for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
  if (params[i] !== '') {
    var attrs = params[i].split('=');
    if (attrs.length) {
      objData[attrs[0]] = attrs[1];
    }
  }
}

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "maintain.aspx",
  data: objData,
  success: function (msg) {
    alert("Done!");
  }

});
console.log(objData)
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/uR8UD/)**

Answer (score -1):

Sorry for the confusion.
Here's an example:

```
var url = "?param1=123&param2=222&param3=aaaa";
var json = {param1: " + getQueryString(url, param1)  + ", param2: " + getQueryString(url, param2)  + "}

function getQueryString(url, param){
        var currentURL ="";
        currentURL = url;
        var separar = currentURL.split("&");
        var value = "";
        for (i = 0; i < separar.length; i++) {
            var separarValue = separar[i].split("=");
            if (separarValue[0] == a) {

                value = separarValue[1];
                break;
            }
        }
        return value;
    }
```

Comment: Um, so you're going to loop through all of the items in the list every time you want to retrieve each item in the list?  You've created an O(n^2) solution to an O(1) problem.